# Jensen's Inequality Clarification

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I'm working on some competition inequalities using some of the inequality theorems I just learned. I am trying to prove:

$$ \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + 8bc}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2 + 8ca}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2 + 8ab}} \ge 1 $$

where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive reals. I recently learned about Jensen's inequality and am trying to apply it to this problem. I've tried something like this:

$$  \frac{a\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a^3 + 8abc}} + \frac{b\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{b^3 + 8abc}} + \frac{c\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{c^3 + 8abc}} \ge 1 $$

and am wondering if I can let:

$$ f(x) = \frac{x\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^3 + 8p}} $$

(where $p = abc$) and use Jensen's inequality. Since $p$ depends on $a$, $b$, and $c$, am I not allowed to use this function for Jensen's inequality? Or because it's a "constant" can I use it anyway?

I've tried to test this for the sum:

$$ \frac{a}{bc} + \frac{b}{ca} + \frac{c}{ba} = \frac{a^2}{abc} + \frac{b^2}{abc} + \frac{c^2}{abc} $$

by defining the function $ f(x) = \frac{x^2}{p} $. Using Jensen's inequality gave me a correct result, but of course this isn't a proof that I can use this trick in general. Thoughts?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I've gone ahead to apply the inequality anyway, and it turns out the $ f(x) $ I've defined for the problem is concave down, so it won't help in proving that the given sum is *greater than or equal to* another number. But it would still be nice to know for future reference if I could use this trick.

**EDIT 2**: Sorry about the wrong signs; it's fixed now!

Comment: As the inequality in question is homogeneous, you may in fact set $abc=1$ WLOG. Thus it's valid.

Comment: In the denominators there should be a plus sign, not a minus one - http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_IMO_Problems/Problem_2

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the wrong sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember how I solved it [a long time ago](http://www.matefilia.it/scolerivolftp/solutori/aprile2002/daurizio.htm). If we set $\frac{bc}{a^2}=x,\frac{ac}{b^2}=y,\frac{ab}{c^2}=z$, we have to prove:
$$ \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+8x}}\geq 1 $$
under the constraint $xyz=1$.

By setting $u=\sqrt{1+8x},v=\sqrt{1+8y},w=\sqrt{1+8z}$ we are left to prove:
$$ \frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{w}\geq 1 $$
under the constraints $u,v,w\geq 1$ and $(u^2-1)(v^2-1)(w^2-1)=512$.

Since the geometric mean is super-additive, we have:
$$GM(u^2,v^2,w^2)\geq 1+GM(u^2-1,v^2-1,w^2-1) = 9 $$
and by the AM-GM inequality it follows that $u+v+w\geq 9$. With the same trick,
$$ GM(u+1,v+1,w+1)\geq 1+GM(u,v,w) \geq 4,$$
so:
$$(u+v+w-1)(u+1)(v+1)(w+1)\geq 8\cdot 4^3 = 512 $$ 
and by exploiting the constraint that is equivalent to:
$$ u+v+w-1 \geq (u-1)(v-1)(w-1) $$
so:
$$ uv+uw+vw \geq uvw $$
as wanted. For a solution using Jensen's inequality, see [the link](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_IMO_Problems/Problem_2) in the comments, or notice that the problem boils down to proving that
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+8x}}$$
is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. Pretty obvious since $f$ is positive and log-convex.

Comment: @Macavity: I think the OP put the wrong signs. It was a IMO problem.

Comment: IMO problem 2001#2 : http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_IMO_Problems/Problem_2

Comment: Ah, there's even a solution by Jensen in that link. +1.

Comment: Sorry about that! I copied down the wrong sign. Good answer!!

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, Would you please give some hint or links about the super-additive for vectors?